# What is a sparse block device at /dev/xvdf

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a thinpool for my docker container. I am following their guide here

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-for-production

It says "It assumes that you have a spare block device at /dev/xvdf with enough free space to complete the task."

I don't have a device at /dev/xvdf. How can I create one?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a block device can be one of the following:

- Hard drive
- Flash drive
- DVD drive
- Blu-ray drive
- etc.

In this case, you need to mount a second hard drive in your server.

Or if you are using Vagrant/Virtualbox for development, you can add new hard disk in `Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager`

1. Open `Settings` page of the box you are working with
2. Select `Storage` from left menu
3. Click [image] to add new hard disk

   - Click `Add Hard Disk`
   - Click `Create new disk`
   - Select `VMDK (Virtual Machine Disk)`
   - Select `Dynamically allocated`
   - Give the disk a name and specify the size of the disk
   - Finally click create
4. Restart the box

You now have a block device to work with, to list the available block device run `lsblk`

[image]

For my case, I have added two hard disks and they are labeled with `/dev/sdb` & `/dev/sdc`

You can use the hard disk to create a physical volume.